# How to use List comprehension to create strings of different sizes from specific characters

Tags: python

I am trying to create a list of strings of length n, where each character is one of "A", "C", "G", or "T".  I can do it for a string of a specific length, say 4 for example:

```
bases = ["A","C","G","T"]
list = [A+B+C+D for A in bases for B in bases for C in bases for D in bases]
```

Now I need to create a function that accepts an argument N, and returns the list of All the possible permutations of that length. Is there a simple way to do this using list comprehension?

I have tried a few different ways, but all have failed.

Comment: Show us what you tried!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product

>>> bases = ["A","C","G","T"]
>>> map(''.join, product(bases, repeat=4))
['AAAA', 'AAAC', 'AAAG', 'AAAT', 'AACA', 'AACC', 'AACG', 'AACT', 'AAGA', 'AAGC', 'AAGG', 'AAGT', 'AATA', 'AATC', 'AATG', 'AATT', 'ACAA', 'ACAC', 'ACAG', 'ACAT', 'ACCA', 'ACCC', 'ACCG', 'ACCT', 'ACGA', 'ACGC', 'ACGG', 'ACGT', 'ACTA', 'ACTC', 'ACTG', 'ACTT', 'AGAA', 'AGAC', 'AGAG', 'AGAT', 'AGCA', 'AGCC', 'AGCG', 'AGCT', 'AGGA', 'AGGC', 'AGGG', 'AGGT', 'AGTA', 'AGTC', 'AGTG', 'AGTT', 'ATAA', 'ATAC', 'ATAG', 'ATAT', 'ATCA', 'ATCC', 'ATCG', 'ATCT', 'ATGA', 'ATGC', 'ATGG', 'ATGT', 'ATTA', 'ATTC', 'ATTG', 'ATTT', 'CAAA', 'CAAC', 'CAAG', 'CAAT', 'CACA', 'CACC', 'CACG', 'CACT', 'CAGA', 'CAGC', 'CAGG', 'CAGT', 'CATA', 'CATC', 'CATG', 'CATT', 'CCAA', 'CCAC', 'CCAG', 'CCAT', 'CCCA', 'CCCC', 'CCCG', 'CCCT', 'CCGA', 'CCGC', 'CCGG', 'CCGT', 'CCTA', 'CCTC', 'CCTG', 'CCTT', 'CGAA', 'CGAC', 'CGAG', 'CGAT', 'CGCA', 'CGCC', 'CGCG', 'CGCT', 'CGGA', 'CGGC', 'CGGG', 'CGGT', 'CGTA', 'CGTC', 'CGTG', 'CGTT', 'CTAA', 'CTAC', 'CTAG', 'CTAT', 'CTCA', 'CTCC', 'CTCG', 'CTCT', 'CTGA', 'CTGC', 'CTGG', 'CTGT', 'CTTA', 'CTTC', 'CTTG', 'CTTT', 'GAAA', 'GAAC', 'GAAG', 'GAAT', 'GACA', 'GACC', 'GACG', 'GACT', 'GAGA', 'GAGC', 'GAGG', 'GAGT', 'GATA', 'GATC', 'GATG', 'GATT', 'GCAA', 'GCAC', 'GCAG', 'GCAT', 'GCCA', 'GCCC', 'GCCG', 'GCCT', 'GCGA', 'GCGC', 'GCGG', 'GCGT', 'GCTA', 'GCTC', 'GCTG', 'GCTT', 'GGAA', 'GGAC', 'GGAG', 'GGAT', 'GGCA', 'GGCC', 'GGCG', 'GGCT', 'GGGA', 'GGGC', 'GGGG', 'GGGT', 'GGTA', 'GGTC', 'GGTG', 'GGTT', 'GTAA', 'GTAC', 'GTAG', 'GTAT', 'GTCA', 'GTCC', 'GTCG', 'GTCT', 'GTGA', 'GTGC', 'GTGG', 'GTGT', 'GTTA', 'GTTC', 'GTTG', 'GTTT', 'TAAA', 'TAAC', 'TAAG', 'TAAT', 'TACA', 'TACC', 'TACG', 'TACT', 'TAGA', 'TAGC', 'TAGG', 'TAGT', 'TATA', 'TATC', 'TATG', 'TATT', 'TCAA', 'TCAC', 'TCAG', 'TCAT', 'TCCA', 'TCCC', 'TCCG', 'TCCT', 'TCGA', 'TCGC', 'TCGG', 'TCGT', 'TCTA', 'TCTC', 'TCTG', 'TCTT', 'TGAA', 'TGAC', 'TGAG', 'TGAT', 'TGCA', 'TGCC', 'TGCG', 'TGCT', 'TGGA', 'TGGC', 'TGGG', 'TGGT', 'TGTA', 'TGTC', 'TGTG', 'TGTT', 'TTAA', 'TTAC', 'TTAG', 'TTAT', 'TTCA', 'TTCC', 'TTCG', 'TTCT', 'TTGA', 'TTGC', 'TTGG', 'TTGT', 'TTTA', 'TTTC', 'TTTG', 'TTTT']
```

Answer (score 0):

If the elements to be combined are single characters, you could do it like this

```
import itertools
bases = ["A", "C", "G", "T"]
premutations = [''.join(comb) for comb in list(itertools.product(bases,repeat=4))]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When posting code, please also try to explain it, so that the OP can understand the code, and not just copy-paste it.

Answer (score -1):

There is a huge `itertools` package:

```
import itertools
alphabets = [ ['a','b'], ['c','d','e'] ]

print [ ''.join(c) for c in itertools.product(*alphabets) ]
```

or with just one alphabet

```
import itertools
alphabet = ['a','b']
size = 2

print [ ''.join(c) for c in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=size) ]
```